# undefined multi offset in calendar script

Tags: php, offset

writes to me :

```
Message: Undefined offset: 1
Message: Undefined offset: 2
Message: Undefined offset: 3
Message: Undefined offset: 4
```

in Line Number: 93

my script:

```
$day = 1;
for($i = 0; $day <= $this->datum->format('t'); $i++ )
{  
   for($j = count($table[$i]); $j < 7 && $day <= $this->datum->format('t'); $j++)
   {
      $table[$i][$j] = $day++;
   }
}
```

line 93:
`for($j = count($table[$i]); $j < 7 && $day <= $this->datum->format('t'); $j++)`

I read the discussion but nothing that would solve my problem.
Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in the referred line you only index the `$table` array, the error output means that the `$table` array does not have an element indexed by 1, 2, 3 or 4.

Without further information about your code, it is unclear why those elements do not exist. I suggest you to output the content of the `$table` array for debug purposes and compare it with the data that should be there.